# Sql Server Xml to table logic

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I need to query Xml data that has multiple REPORT tag elements. It needs to be filtered to return only the rows where the REPORTID is equal to a given name. I've tried to perform this filter with no luck. Could someone point me in the right direction here using the Sql Server Xml functions?

Basically, I'm looking for my result set to return as a table and look like:

```
ID
------
1
2
3
```

Given the following, how would I select out on the rows for the REPORT where the REPORTID (/TEST/REPORT/TITLE[@ReportId = "Report One"]) is equal to 'Report One'?

```
DECLARE @Xml XML, @ReportId VARCHAR(200);
SET @ReportId = 'Report One';

SET @Xml = '
<TEST>
<REPORT ReportType="Type One">
  <TITLE ReportId="Report One">
    <TITLE1>Title One</TITLE1>
  </TITLE>
  <HEADER>
    <Run_Date OrigName="Run Date">4/10/2012</Run_Date>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <TABLE1>
      <DATA />
      <ROW>
        <ID>1</ID>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ID>2</ID>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ID>3</ID>
      </ROW>
    </TABLE1>
  </BODY>
</REPORT>
<REPORT ReportType="Type Two">
  <TITLE ReportId="Report Two">
    <TITLE1>Title Two</TITLE1>
  </TITLE>
  <HEADER>
    <Run_Date OrigName="Run Date">4/10/2012</Run_Date>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <TABLE1>
      <DATA />
      <ROW>
        <ID>4</ID>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ID>5</ID>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ID>6</ID>
      </ROW>
    </TABLE1>
  </BODY>
</REPORT>
</TEST>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select I.N.value('.', 'int') as ID 
from @Xml.nodes('TEST/REPORT') as R(N)
  cross apply R.N.nodes('BODY/TABLE1/ROW/ID') as I(N)
where R.N.exist('TITLE[@ReportId = sql:variable("@ReportId")]') = 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I had just started playing around with cross applying nodes. I just found this article which helped me understand it a bit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/04/24/flattening-xml-data-in-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is almost three years old, but I couldn't resist.  The CROSS APPLY is unnecessary if you expand the XPATH expression in nodes().

```
SELECT  ID = c.value('.', 'int')
FROM @Xml.nodes('/TEST/REPORT[TITLE/@ReportId=sql:variable("@ReportId")]/BODY/TABLE1/ROW/ID') x(c)
```